# Populate selectable field from DB in Zend 2 Album example

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2

I'm starting programming with Zend and I am using the default Album example they provide as a "getting started" guide.

I would like to have a select drop down field in the form, but I can't find an easy way of doing it like the code is right now

This is how I'm doing it without consulting DB from my UsersForm.php

```
$this->add(array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
    'name' => 'level',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'User level',
        'value_options' => array(
                    '1' => 'admin',
                    '2' => 'boss',
                    '3' => 'assistent',
                    '4' => 'client',
        ),
    ),
));
```

### UPDATE

Ok, so following that tutorial using TableGateway I managed to have a selectable but is grabbing data from the 'project' table because the rest of my fields need that table, but I need that selectable to get from 'user' table.

My Module.php looks like this:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(),
        'factories' => array(
            'Project\Model\ProjectTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $projectTableGateway = $sm->get('ProjectTableGateway');
                $usersTableGateway = $sm->get('UsersTableGateway');
                $table = new ProjectTable($projectTableGateway, $usersTableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'project-model-selectable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('selecttable-gateway');
                $table = new SelectTable($projectTableGateway, $usersTableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'ProjectTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Project());
                return new TableGateway('project', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
            'UsersTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Users());
                return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
            'selecttable-gateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter          = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new SelectOption());
                return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

And my getProject function in ProjectTable.php:

```
public function getProject($id)
    {
        $id  = (int) $id;

        $rowset = $this->projectTableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (!$row) {
            throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
        }
        return $row;
    }
```

My addAction in ProjectController.php

```
public function addAction()
    {
        $tableGateway = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Project\Model\ProjectTable');
        $form = new ProjectForm($tableGateway);
        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Nuevo');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {

            $project = new ProjectForm($tableGateway);
            $form->setInputFilter($project->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $project->exchangeArray($form->getData());
                $this->getProjectTable()->saveProject($project);

                // Redirect to list of projects
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('project');
            }
        }
        return array('form' => $form);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: do you want to prepare a select element with DB options?

Comment: http://samminds.com/2013/03/zendformelementselect-and-database-values/ sam described it in his blog post pretty well.

Comment: I've updated the question after some progress. Thanks

Comment: what exactly do you mean by they need the project table? cant you just have a query which gets you those statuses or are they in relation to the project? Can you post your sql structure?

Comment: It is a list of projects, when adding a new one or editing an existing one, you get the usual 'name', 'summary' and one of them is a selectable which lets you select an user as a project manager. So I need for the rest to query in 'project' table to get the project info and the selectable needs to query in the 'user' table to get the list of users

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getProject($id)
{
    $id  = (int) $id;

    $rowset = $this->projectTableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
    $row = $rowset->current();
    if (!$row) {
        throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
    }
    return $row;
}
```